# google app engine local server doesn't work run after multiple times in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

After running app-engine java project multiple times in eclipse, app-engine local server doesn't work. I am getting error "This webpage is not available" in Google chrome. But eclipse console says that "dev App Server is now running". But using `dev_appserver.cmd` works fine, it is too difficult when developing the project. Any ideas to solve this?

PS: rerunning is done after stopping the current execution of the server.

Answer (score 2):

Choose '**Automatically select an unused port**' in debug configuration.
Local server will start every time on different port, but it should solve your problem.

Comment: Where is that setting exactly?

Answer (score 0):

try to change the configuration by "run as" or "debug as" and check server and port no.
**Also ensure that in Windows>>preference>>java>>jre a path to jdk (not jre) is selected.**
Please provide more details of the problem if it is still there.

Comment: Tried "debug as" but no result, all paths are correct. Now I figured out `dev_appserver.cmd` is also not working after some time.

Comment: try adding 
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\javaw.exe in eclipse.ini file, before -vmargs

Comment: go to windows>>show view>>general>>problems to see any problems with validation

Comment: Problems panel doesn't show up anything, I'll try adding argument. It's working after restart the machine. I think it might be a OS problem or SDK problem can anyone help with this?